# LOG: could not open temporary-files directory "base/

Tags: macos, postgresql

When I try to start postgresql, I get this error:  I restored the db from tape backup into a share in the XSAN.  Help! Anyone....

```
192:Database postgres$ sudo -u postgres /opt/local/lib/postgresql82/bin/pg_ctl restart -m immediate -D /Volumes/Database
pg_ctl: PID file "/Volumes/Database/postmaster.pid" does not exist
Is server running?
starting server anyway
server starting
192:Database postgres$ LOG:  could not open temporary-files directory "base/._1/pgsql_tmp": Not a directory
LOG:  could not open temporary-files directory "base/._320517/pgsql_tmp": Not a directory
LOG:  could not open temporary-files directory "base/._16385/pgsql_tmp": Not a directory
LOG:  could not open temporary-files directory "base/._10818/pgsql_tmp": Not a directory
LOG:  could not open temporary-files directory "base/._10819/pgsql_tmp": Not a directory
LOG:  could not open temporary-files directory "base/._1987165/pgsql_tmp": Not a directory
LOG:  could not open temporary-files directory "base/._2530683/pgsql_tmp": Not a directory
LOG:  could not open temporary-files directory "base/._2506219/pgsql_tmp": Not a directory
LOG:  could not open temporary-files directory "base/._1603212/pgsql_tmp": Not a directory
LOG:  could not open temporary-files directory "base/._1603283/pgsql_tmp": Not a directory
LOG:  could not open temporary-files directory "base/._1603172/pgsql_tmp": Not a directory
LOG:  could not open temporary-files directory "base/._1201502/pgsql_tmp": Not a directory
LOG:  logger shutting down
```

Comment: FYI this is off topic for Stack Overflow; please consider deleting the question and posting in dba.stackexchange.com or serverfault.com .

Comment: At a guess you are trying to run PostgreSQL over a network file system like AFP or CIFS. This will not work. Use a local HFS+ volume on Mac OS X. NFS might also work if Apple's NFS implementation is correct and you use it in synchronous mode with the locking daemon enabled, but I haven't tested it with Apple stuff.